# why does object.assign not combine all the source objects into the target

Tags: javascript, object, axios

my code is :

```
  return await axios
    .all(requests)
    .then(
      axios.spread(async (...responses) => {
        let fish = [...responses].map((e) => e.data.results);
        let newFish = Object.assign({}, ...fish);
        console.log(fish, 'and', newFish);
      }),
    )
```

a console.log of fish shows:

[(Object of 100 keys), (Object of 100 keys),(Object of 100 keys),(Object of 70 keys)]

but a console.log of newFish instead of being the desired :
(Object of 370 keys)

shows
(object of 100 keys)

This suggests object. assign is overwriting instead of combining.

Why does it do this?

I need to do

return Object.addign({},...responses)

and have this combine all the objects into one object

more info:

OBJECT WITH 100 keys:

[image]

all objects

[image]

All have a unique id and are alphabetically ordered. every value is completely unique.

Object with 100 keys is a combination of the last object with 100 keys and the last object that has only 70 keys.
[image]

as you can see here in how it adds more after 70
[image]

Comment: 370 would only be the case when all keys are unique. I would guess that only 70 of them are unique.

Comment: Though at a minimum 100 must be unique.

Comment: You could try reducing instead of mapping. `let fish = [...responses].reduce((res, e) => Object.assign(res, e.data.results), {});`

Comment: Well the first thing to do is get more details about what those "Objects with 100 keys" look like **in detail**.  `Object.assign()` is not broken; it *does* overwrite when a source object has a key that is the same as that of a property in a target object; an object can only have one key with a given name so that's really all it can do. However, if you have unique keys, you'd end up with a populated object as you expect.

Comment: Also `[... responses].map()` needlessly makes a copy of the `responses` array (in addition to the new array built by `.map()`).

Comment: @pilchard Yes... That should have been a 100 and not 70. Which makes the _"shows (object of 70 keys)"_ even weirder...

Comment: it is done alphabetically, they are all unique

Comment: If that were true, you would not be having the problem. Debugging is about finding which ones of your assumptions are incorrect.

Comment: i mean, it is showing the objects as separate arrays.

if 100 is in one object, then why would it be reduced to 70? These are very much all alphabetical, the 70 are the last ones from about p to z

Comment: @pilchard This is more about making it work than tidying, as you can see by the console.log of fish, the map is not the problem

Comment: I have no idea; it's your code. Instead of just thinking about "object with 100 keys" you need to look at **exactly** their compositions.

Comment: You can go to your browser console right now and try `Object.assign({}, {a: 1}, {b: 2})` to confirm that the method does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: One thing: you might want to verify that `axios.spread()` can deal with an `async` function properly. It doesn't seem to me that that would be part of the problem, but I don't see any mention of `.spread()` accepting an `async` callback.

Comment: sorry, yes it seems that it was brought back up to 100 with newFish

Comment: The problem seems to be about a static limit of 100 objects

Comment: Your "objects" are **arrays**. The "id" properties within the individual elements have nothing to do with how `Object.assign()` works: it will only pay attention to the object keys, which for an array are the array indexes.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense,

Comment: so you actually want to `let newFish = [].concat(...fish);` or `let newFish = fish.flat();`